# Android HttpURLConnection VERY slow

Tags: android, timeout, httpurlconnection, galaxy

This is the situation I'm facing with the code below:

As you can see I'm trying to read an HTTP stream. When I run the following code on the Android simulator it works 100% of the time, when I run the following code on my Galaxy S3 while on 3G it works 100% of the time, when I try to connect to the URL using my laptop browser it works 100% of the time, when I try to connect using the Galaxy S3 browser (in both wifi and 3g) it works... 100% of the time.  HOWEVER, when I try to connect using my Galaxy S3 while on Wi-Fi I time out ~80% of the time.  If I remove the timeout properties I get weird exceptions such as:

```
"recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT"
"failed to connect to <URL>: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)"
"unable to resolve the host <URL>: no address associated with hostname"
```

I'm open to any suggestions...

```
public static final String getHttpResponse(String url)
{
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    InputStream response = null;
    try { 
        URL address = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)address.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000); //30 seconds
        conn.setReadTimeout(30 * 1000); //30 seconds

        response = conn.getInputStream();

        if(conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
            Log.e("Util.getHttpResponse", Integer.toString(conn.getResponseCode()));
            return null; 
        }

        String result = Util.streamToString(response);
        return result;

    } catch(IOException e) {
        response = conn.getErrorStream();
        Log.e("Util.getHttpResponse", Util.streamToString(response));
        return null;

    } finally { 
        if( response != null ) { 
            try {
                response.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(conn != null) { 
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
- using AndroidHttpClient did not work
- After getting the input stream I had an error popup right in the eclipse IDE... As you can see my debug cursor made it all the way to line 107.. well after I was done getting the input stream this time...
[image: Eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem on Android device. I use an IP address in the url. Final, I found the HttpURLConnection.connect(...) method involved the getHostName() internally. After that, I use the domain in the url, then it works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, what if you try using `AndroidHttpClient` class instead for doing the same? It has some predefined timeouts and other settings which, we were told, should work fine in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot and reply back. However, I did try using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient and was getting the same results.