# HttpURLConnection very slow

Tags: java, android

Can anyone spot why this takes ~20 sec?
I am running the code below to post a JSON request to a local server 192.168.1.127.

> curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST
>   http:// 192.168.1.127:8080/bed -d
>   '{"command":{"value":3.012,"set":"target_pressure_voltage"},"id":2002,"side":"left","role":"command"}'

curl on the same box where the server is running is instant and the server does not complain.

A get request from the Android browser is fast. I have tried two Android devices with os version 4.x.

This question does not help as far as I can tell:
[Android HttpURLConnection VERY slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108166/android-httpurlconnection-very-slow)

**con.getInputStream()** Takes ~20 sec:

```
    String httpJson(String url, JSONObject job) {
    String ret = null;      
        HttpURLConnection con = httpJsonCon(url);
        if(con!=null)
            httpJsonCon(con, url,job);      
    return ret;

}



 HttpURLConnection mkCon(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    URL u = null;
    try {
        u = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) (u.openConnection());

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/plain");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.connect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, " e= " + e);
        if(con!=null)
            con.disconnect();

        con = null;
    }

    return con;
}

String sendJson(HttpURLConnection con, JSONObject job) {
    String ret = null;
    if(con==null){
        return ret;
    }

    try {
        final String toWriteOut = job.toString();

        final Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(
                con.getOutputStream()), "UTF-8");
        out.write(toWriteOut);
        out.flush();
        //con.getInputStream() Takes ~20 sec:
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));  



    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, " e= " + e);

        ret = null;
    } finally {
        if(con!=null)
            con.disconnect();
    }

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: Try your POST request in a tool like REST Console, from your local workstation, using Chrome, with Developer Tools enabled. Run it a couple times and observe the time taken for each request. Then compare your results with how long its taking from the device.

Comment: What takes 20 seconds? The first method? Or the second one?

Comment: The slow call is in the second function: con.getInputStream()

Comment: Try actually reading the data sent back by the server.

Comment: I have tried reading. Same problem.

Comment: @JohanvdH did you find the solution? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a request header that specifies the post content length.

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + json.length());
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would this speed up the call?

Comment: Great question. I should have included a reference. This was long enough ago that I don't remember. The best thing I can think of is either a bug in an early version of android, or allowing clients to calculate time left for debugging purposes.